# Puppeteer: javascript file tagged as "xhr" type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm capturing network requests from a page using Puppeteer. Some of the network requests have a url path that indicates a javascript file and a `resourceType` of `xhr`. Does that mean that the file path is the instantiator of the the request or is another script making an HTTP request for that file?[image]

Answer (score 1):

xhr means the file is loading via Ajax. Another script is making an HTTP(S) request for that file.

Comment: Right, understand that. My question is, in this context is that what Puppeteer is trying to indicate? I assume it is.